# Sending mail to detailed groups?

Tags: 7, emails

Ok, I need a bit of help with this one.

I have a website where I created a newsletter using Simplenews - works just fine, I'm sending some welcoming text + attached views of new things on site. But now I need to make something more with it.

I want to create new type of newsletter, that would be sent irregularly - or manualy as some would say. That is not a problem. Question appears here: I want admin to be able to create groups of users (manually again adding mails to the group etc.) for example, let's say I want to have two new groups for start:

- group a
- group b

And from time to time, admin needs to send a mail to all the email addresses in the selected group. How can I achieve that? Is even Simplenews a good idea in this situation? Or maybe there's some better tool?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you know about OG?

Comment: You mean Organic Groups? Only heard about it, but newer used it. I believe I should check it?

Comment: I checked Organic Groups and I'm rather sure it's NOT what I'm looking for. I must be able to create/manage at least few groups of subscriptions (based on email address, not registered users) and be able to send mass mail to selected group manually.

Answer (score 0):

I guess **[Simplenews Roles](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews_roles)** modules can help you for creating the groups.

You can assign users to a specific role and then based on this roles you can send Simplenews.

For Eg.

User 1 and User 2 can be assigned to role A

And

User 3 and User 4 can be assigned to role B

Now you can use role A and B for sending Simplenews.

I guess this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simplenews exactly has this feature:

1. First create groups here "admin/config/services/simplenews/add"
2. Edit new content type and in "Publishing options" check "Use as
   simplenews newsletter"